# Как поменять тип даты?

Tags: python, datetime

Есть переменная:

```py
a = '12.05.2020'
```

Надо как-то из неё получить эту переменную:

```py
b = '2020-05-12'
```

Comment: "-".join(a.split(".")[::-1])

Comment: @КириллМалышев Хорошо, но с датами меньше 10 числа будет не очень красиво, если они будут без нулей впереди изначально

Comment: Дубликат же, найдите, кому не лень

Answer (score 5):

Можно воспользоваться стандартной библиотекой [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

***Пример:***

```py
from datetime import datetime

a = '12.05.2020'
dt = datetime.strptime(a, '%d.%m.%Y')  # type: datetime.datetime
b = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')            # type: str
print(b)
```

***stdout:***

```py
2020-05-12
```

Comment: Эх, немного я не успел, удалил свой такой же вариант )

Answer (score 1):

Или так:

```
a = '12.05.2020'
b = a[6:] + '-' + a[3:5] + '-' + a[:2] 
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = '-'.join(reversed(a.split('.')))
```